# Umbraco install page doesn't load, redirects to itself

Tags: c#, asp.net, umbraco, umbraco7, umbraco8

I have recieved an installed copy of umbraco from my client and i have added the DB name manually in web. config file. When i tried to run the code the page is getting redirected.

http://localhost:54918/install/?redir=true&url=http%3a%2f%2flocalhost%3a54918%2f#?redir=true&url=http:%2F%2Flocalhost:54918%2F

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Check your web.config file. You should have ConfigurationStatus and connectionStrings.

```
  <add key="Umbraco.Core.ConfigurationStatus" value="<UMBRACO_VERSION>" />

  <connectionStrings>
     <add name="umbracoDbDSN" connectionString="<YOUR_CONNECTION_STRING>" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
  </connectionStrings>
```

Umbraco has great UI for installation <YOUR_DOMAIN>/install. After filling it you can run Umbraco.